# Get the content of an <input> textbox with Python

Tags: python, html, upload, tornado

I'm using a Tornado server running with Python, whose job in convert a .svg file in several font formats. For now I managed to make it generate a fontpack in a .zip file by clicking on a  button. My Python code links with html form by using `self.request.files['filearg']` where filearg is the name of the file selected in an `<input type="file">` box.

But I'd like to make this submit button communicate with a text box in which I'd fill the output format I want my file converted in.

Basically, what I'd want in my html form would look like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="post">
    File: <input type="file" name="filearg" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="format"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate font(s)" />
</form>
```

I managed to do it with a Node.js server (with fields.format and so on), but I can't find any way to do this in Python.

I've heard about the CGI forms in HTML, which can permit to get this kind of content. But as if it's not the kind of form I chose, I wonder whether it can be implemented with my actual form.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tornado documentation explains how to get the values of form fields, using [`get_argument`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=fields#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_argument):

```
format = self.get_argument("format")
```

Comment: Woops. Looks like I missed that part of the doc. Kudos!